# How to remove columns space in column chart

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I am using `HighChart.dll` to use high charts in ASP.NET

Rendering Chart: Column

Now I want to remove extra space between columns.

```
chart.PlotOptions = New Core.PlotOptions.PlotOptionsColumn() With { _
                .showInLegend = True,
                .borderWidth = 0,
                .groupPadding = 0,
                .shadow = False,
                .minPointLength = -200,
                .borderColor = "#dedede", _
                .borderRadius = 2 _
            }
```

I am not getting suitable properties in above code block to remove spaces

Answer (score 1):

I see groupPadding there, but I don't see pointPadding set:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding\

Both affect space between columns.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add [**`pointpadding`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointPadding) in the plot options.

```
 plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0, 
            shadow: true
        }
    }
```

or

```
chart.PlotOptions = New Core.PlotOptions.PlotOptionsColumn() With { _
            .showInLegend = True,
            .borderWidth = 0,
            .pointPadding = 0,
            .groupPadding = 0,
            .shadow = False,
            .minPointLength = -200,
            .borderColor = "#dedede", _
            .borderRadius = 2 _
        }
```

`groupPadding` is used to provide spacing between the column groups whereas `pointPadding` is used to induce or specify the space between the points, more appropriately, columns.

Is [**`this`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/Tk2sj/) what you are expecting ?

Comment: But pointPadding is not valid properties in my code. please refer this screen-shot: http://tinypic.com/r/f10adf/5

Answer (score 0):

According to source code of that wrapper, it's not possible to set `pointPadding`:

http://highcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Highchart/Highchart/Core/Options/PlotOptionsColumn.cs

Another solution would be to set `pointWidth`, but this is also not supported.

```
namespace Highchart.Core.PlotOptions
{

[Serializable]
public class PlotOptionsColumn : PlotOptionsSeries
{
    public string borderColor { get; set; }
    public int? borderRadius { get; set; }
    public int? borderWidth { get; set; }
    public bool? colorByPoint { get; set; }
    public int? groupPadding { get; set; }
    public int? minPointLength { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string ignored = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore });

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ignored))
        {
            return string.Format("plotOptions: {{ series: {0} }},", ignored);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

}

}
```

Good luck..